# How to get value from dropdown in datatables cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've got two **datatables** and there is a **dropdown** created in the second one with data from the first. I've created a jsbin [here](http://live.datatables.net/hoqumugu/1/)

If you add a couple of instructions to the first table (add any text and then click Add Instruction) - then click on the `Load Copied Data` button, you will see the dropdown box is populated from the first table.

If I do:

```
$('#btnTest').on('click', function (e) {

    var tsor = $('#tblSORSInstall').dataTable();
    var ins = tsor.fnGetData();


    alert(ins);

});
```

It basically gives me the html for the **dropdown** - how do I get which value they have chosen? I was thinking of having a hidden column and updating that on the `onchange` of the **dropdown**, but is there a better way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: how do you select row? my mean's you want trace one by one the rows and get selected value? Or you want select a row by it's custom attribute then get selected value of it?

Comment: try this `tsor.fnGetNodes()` to get all the nodes.

Comment: @SiamakFerdos I want it for all rows

Comment: something like [this?](http://live.datatables.net/jabanene/1/)

Comment: @CerlinBoss exactly like that! Thank you - if you want to add an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `tsor.fnGetNodes()` you can get all table row nodes, then you can loop through those and get the select values.

Final code will look something like

```
 $('#btnTest').on('click', function (e) {
    var tsor = $('#tblSORSInstall').dataTable();
    var ins = tsor.fnGetData();
    var a = tsor.fnGetNodes();
    $.each(tsor.fnGetNodes(), function (index, value) {
        alert($(value).find('select').val());
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) to generate an array of selected text/value, like below.

```
$('#btnTest').on('click', function (e) {

    //var tsor = $('#tblSORSInstall').dataTable();

    var ins = $('#tblSORSInstall').find("tbody select").map(function() {

        return $(this).find(":selected").text() // get selected text
        //return $(this).val() // get selected value

    }).get()

    alert ( JSON.stringify(ins, null, 2) )

});
```

Here is your [JS Bin - updated](http://live.datatables.net/yonelano/1)

Comment: Thank you, that's great and along the same lines of Cerlin's answer - +1 for the map function which I'd never seen before :)